# PHP mysql selecting MAX()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Trying to select `MAX()` in `PHP MySQL`, but no result is shown as well no error shown (error display are on

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

).

[image]

**I tried:**

```
$user_home = new USER();

$select_max = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT MAX(Gems) AS highest FROM users"); 
$get_max = $select_max->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
$highest = $get_max['highest'];
echo $highest;
```

**Class File:**

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $database = new Database();
        $db = $database->dbConnection();
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    public function runQuery($sql)
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        return $stmt;
    }
```

Comment: What does `runQuery()` do?

Comment: @NigelRen updated question by solving your query.

Comment: Clearly your code is incomplete, which might be intentional. Any syntax error in your main file could result in no output at all, even if you have error displaying enabled. Better do `echo "[$highest]";` instead of `echo $highest;`. If you see `[]` as output then your query doesn't work, if you see nothing then there's a syntax error somewhere.

Comment: Nice tip @KIKOSoftware this way we may get the point!

Comment: For PDO it's a one-liner problem: `$highest = $pdo->query("SELECT MAX(Gems) FROM users")->fetchColumn();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't executing the query, just preparing it and the fetching the data...

```
$select_max = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT MAX(Gems) AS highest FROM users"); 
$select_max->execute();
$get_max = $select_max->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
$highest = $get_max['highest'];
echo $highest;
```

Comment: Ohh! A silly mistake.., any suggestions for my code? Is my way of coding is correct?